# Typescript Interface combined with keys of map on object property

Tags: typescript

I'm attempting to create a means by to create handlers which all share the same basic definition but then have additional properties which are specific to each use.

I have a router, a context and route handler functions which accept the context as a parameter. I would like to be able to attach additional properties to the context depending on the route definition.

If a route definition is `/hello/:user`, there's a parameter `user` and when called as `HTTP GET /hello/ben` that'd be the value of said parameter.

As such we have `context.params = {user: 'ben'}` in this particular instance.

I also register lookup functions for these params.

I.e. `context.bindings['user] = (param) => User.find(param)`

When i register the routes, I want the handlers containing the context and any additional keys which were resolved by lookup functions. For example

```
// In this example, each GET route has a :parameter and a binding for it so their
// handler should receive the result of the binding function as a key on context
// Both receive params because that's just part of context always.

router.binding('user', (user) => User.find(user));
router.binding('photo', (photo) => Photo.find(photo));
router.get("/bar/:photo", ({ params, photo }: HttpContextContract) => {}) // 1
router.get("/bar/:user", ({ params, user }: HttpContext) => {}) // 2

// in (1), the interface HttpContextContract doesn't know about photo so it moans
// in (2), the class HttpContext just lets any property go and there's no helpful typing/intellisense etc
```

I don't want to have to define a new interface each time for each route `HttpContextContract & { user: User }` for example. I believe I should be able to use something along the lines of `type Handlers = Record<keyof typeof handlers, {}>` but I can't seem to get it to work.

I've put together a basic example of the pieces described above and put it into a [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAQglgOwCaIOZQLxQBRgIYBOeAtgFxQDOwBaAlJgHxR4IgBQokUASgPYCuwCAAkWSADYQCmHAGNgAD3LDgwMAGFeCIQuCbtRefQxMWIANxs2iIQQBmeWdD6CI8ZGgpQA3myhQAbQBrCBByKhoEVABdcncUKLYAXysbKQcnHgEhUWRJAi9ff2DQ8Oo0WKzXXIkpSxTrbXTHaBU1fR09LWpHYB8-KHwiYgpyM3rUpvsWqDaNbohdfv9ikLDKcqjK8agAel2oYAALOC88cXFeAHcvYmhgXmZVRyPDo+gECCuoNa8Ht+giCoLCcySssnEeAoXjmHUWfTgxDAkju2hhqnmTV0HUMfSKg34ACNxHBZINCCRRsxWDJvA0GhCoV4XLZlgTiaSoITEAlUFSWW4eZ5aSl-GAiSSyUcxPl+dkRDKpF4sHTLANxRyydyPFFsGsypFUAAaLlCqJxM2oej4-zHU4AOm1vIoJRA0RkTrQAwaYolnNQEGAuDwxwNaBN0ryUjGrGtA1tJwo9sjtQKAXwx3dWBT+Us-h97MlUDsPODoY2hto5AFNXybP8BED-AICDeDpzSvTIaO0TzUBSDMh0KgAGUpAA3KRs2RaCL8eS8Ai4Ai8ITyCBIKAr1wEavygjW-tWfwB4AABQpIzLRzDUTjKygM4QVCgxBDsneyvJx3tb+AH+wXZSGwAIAD0AB1dmiABqWhdjgK0oAAHyQwJonjLcmxbV930-X88DAbBlSYJMKCJCI0GwABGWhaG9Y8oA7a9b0Qm1H1nPp5AUGRPm+WEFl0bBaHMPYDihWYMThJYADIfCgAByOxeF4AAmeTyHkwlCAUgsEwdU8L2GChr1oe0lIIABRF5sGDYYWOMJg2P8J8X09KIZDtJNt1sR1LRdIYSF7DD-DgOwcDc1jgpWfYoAAeUJAArCB5HtJAIBLT4zxXSACFAbAuJNALiBNJzooOE9A3ICKov8GKkmEh8Vhqx9FC7YYs1NHVUFskhhKi0UVnqjCMJcvoO2kLBPPtbypDM0sMyOOiH0bYBm1bcb8sUJajwZDit33HiviqWwhMsUbKAnKcsF40dLqXGaDzVRlhzPI5V0eNjRoIecHiXDUiwQEgIHsnwBysB7fK67B5P4CgpHkk0hMYBSYFigBVAA5AARKA0ZHCzuFHAAVbgAEkMYAcXkuiIYi6GwDeh4EZwByoBu173uhoQqGpui2BionE0Y8SEEeOA0rwZhCWyAEoFhqcwGyqRQBNCBJ1bY4BFQV44GAeS-neRtqU3Rs8CQPBiQgNgIdPaHdiU3ggPlghmewbw5bh6QkmUSSBK6AxelZ-EVrWqAAAMACIABJvGdpII6gAAeABaYsV2ITrnTD+o+v5g5BdONnrigSRgFuaB5cGRneBNQlBCgJBeAgCgEHkvohAuV8K89hum5btuoEWU528Nq2bcDO2tIIICGfe133dnh4TWd-sffaP2g4GEPsMjmOACkR1ijH7QoqJQpAXBq5NBB+AuE0VNoJIoBjuOE5TtPeAziKKGz5Jc-O7IVEZCe0nAQZMio7YOydp7ambAAGCBUsAu64CoyT0IDPausC4Gzl4JIe0lxuqALoi5XBEB8G8EIQgvmMVODQAsroCAyANxZV4DlYAcBm6JyJkwFUgQzxQEQD8UIvAwpE0qETAIZ53RJEsDFWS9ChBMKQCwthHCKCJ24MlRcSBE5rBEYccAEB9FTQeiVJIDAGCyIOLQ2AMAZACgIAEeS40KDyXQjQwxsxFQFHsVoggOi9FhVofolxZiGBAA)) so hopefully it's easier to see roughly what i'm trying to achieve

```
type Binding = (param: string) => any;
type RouteHandler = (ctx: HttpContextContract) => any;

interface RouteBindings {
  [key: string]: Binding;
}

interface RouteHandlers {
  [key: string]: RouteHandler;
}

interface HttpContextContract {
  params: any;
}

interface HttpContext {
  [key: string]: any; // this allows me to attach the new keys to the instance
}

class HttpContext implements HttpContextContract {
  public params: any = {};
}

class Router {
  public bindings: RouteBindings = {};
  public handlers: RouteHandlers = {};

  public binding(key: string, binding: Binding) {
    this.bindings[key] = binding;
  }

  public get(path: string, handler: any) {
    this.handlers[path] = handler;
  }

  public find(path: string): RouteHandler {
    return this.handlers[path];
  }
}

class Server {
  constructor(protected router: Router) {}

  getParams(path: string) {
    const matches = path.match(/:([^/]+)/gi) || [];
    return matches.map(s => s.substring(1));
  }

  handle(path: string) {
    const ctx = new HttpContext(); // as HttpContext & { 'foo2': 'bar '}

    this.getParams(path).forEach((param: string) => {
      const binding = this.router.bindings[param];
      if (binding) {
        // Object.defineProperty(ctx, param, {
        //   get: binding
        // });
        ctx[param] = binding(param);
      }
    });

    const handler = this.router.find(path);
    return handler(ctx);
  }
}

const router = new Router();
const server = new Server(router);

class Photo {
  constructor(public name: string) {}
}

router.binding("user", () => "BOUND USER STRING");
router.binding("photo", () => new Photo("test"));

// This has no idea about the user property, even though it's there and readable
router.get("/foo/:user", ({ user }: HttpContextContract) => {
  return `"${user}" <- from bindings`;
});

// This now lets me use photo, but doesn't tell me user doesn't exist there
router.get("/bar/:photo", ({ photo, user }: HttpContext) => {
  return `"${JSON.stringify(photo, null, 2)} ${user}" <- from bindings`;
});

const out1 = server.handle("/foo/:user");
const out2 = server.handle("/bar/:photo");

console.log(out1);
console.log(out2);

// type ExtendedProperties<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] };
// & ExtendedProperties<Record<keyof typeof this.router, {}>>;
// type BB = Router['handlers']
// type Handlers = Record<keyof typeof handlers, {}>
```

Comment: You're asking typescript to analyze what is in a string. It isn't possible as far as I know. You can create literals e.g. `const s = 'user' as const` but knowing what to do based on a template string is beyond the typing. Unforutnalyt if you want typescript to work well, you need to meet it halfway and confirm your code such that it can be typed.

Comment: Could accept a certain level of chaining? like `router.binding('..').binding('..').get()` ?
In this way I think it is feasible and if it's ok to you, I'll prepare an answer

Comment: @leonardfactory that'd be one option which would allow me to specifically add bindings to individual routes which i was hoping to add on top after getting the more general one to work. my example above allows for any defined route to pick up on available bindings from the router, whereas yours would only allow that route definition to get the binding?

Answer (score 0):

I think your current API is a little bit too dynamic for TypeScript to handle. But here's something that might help.

```js
class Router<T extends Record<string, () => any> = {}> {
  bindings: T;

  constructor(handlers: T) {
    this.bindings = handlers;
  }

  bind<Key extends string, Handler>(key: Key, handler: Handler) {
    return new Router<{ [key in Key]: Handler} & T>({ 
      ...this.bindings, 
      ...({ [key]: handler } as { [key in Key]: Handler }) 
    });
  }
}
function createRouter() {
  return new Router({});
}

const router = createRouter()
  .bind('hello', () => "world")
  .bind('foo', () => Math.random());
const handler = router.bindings.hello; // const helloHandler: () => "world"
const fooHandler = router.bindings.foo; // const fooHandler: () => number
```

As long as you use string literals in the call to `.bind()`, you'll keep the types of the callbacks.

**Edit:** Here's a tweaked version that you can hopefully build what you need from.

```js
// builds typed objects one property at a time
// ex. const obj = new Builder({}).add("hello", "world").build();
class Builder<T> {
  readonly obj: T;
  constructor(value: T) {
    this.obj = value;
  }
  add<K extends string, V>(key: K, value: V) {
    let next = {...this.obj, ...({[key]: value} as { [key in K]: V })};
    return new Builder(next);
  }
  build(): T { // finish building the object
    return this.obj;
  }
}

class Route<T> {
  bindings: T;
  path: string;

  constructor(path: string, bindings: (builder: Builder<{}>) => Builder<T>) {
    this.path = path;
    this.bindings = bindings(new Builder({})).build();
  }
}

let route = new Route("/api", (bindings) => bindings
  .add("hello", "world")
  .add("person", () => Math.random())
);
```

Comment: The router API is something i can change. the key is that the handlers must accept something consistent right at the final use i.e. `(context: HttpContextContract) => {` for example. In your example above, presumably you'd just spread bindings into context so that those properties are available in the route handler? Also, that'd make all bindings available to all contexts. Can i scope the bindings available to a route?

Comment: You could create bindings specific to routes similar to my second example. If you need to inject default properties as well as the bindings, you can use an intersection type: `(context: HttpContextContract & T) => {`